# How to keep only column-specific content?

Tags: bash, text, awk, duplicates, multiple-columns

I've been looking around but I can't fing anything coming close to what I am searching for. 
I think an example will explain it better to start with :
Input :

```
------------------------------------|
|   List1   |   List2   |   List3   |
|     1     |     2     |     3     |
|     2     |     3     |     4     |
|     3     |     4     |     5     |
|     4     |     5     |     6     |
|     5     |     6     |     7     |
|     6     |     7     |     a     |
|     7     |     8     |     b     |
|     a     |     d     |     c     |
```

Desired Output :

```
------------------------------------|
|   List1   |   List2   |   List3   |
|     1     |     8     |     b     |
|           |     d     |     c     |
```

So, as you can see, the goal is to keep in each column only content that is not found elsewhere in the table. Ideally this should work with any number of columns.

Anything in awk, bash, or even in excel would be fine. 
So far I've played around with awk, but to no avail.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks everyone.

Edit, to clarify.
The actual input are different lists I want to compare. Ideally they are each in a different file. Now, I can easily merge them to match the input given in example so that the code provided here in the answers is applicable.

Comment: Is that REALLY your input or are you trying to show us what your real input file (e.g. a CSV or similar) would look like if it were drawn as a table?

Comment: Yes, it is an example of what it would look like, not the actual input.

Comment: Wish you'd just posted your real input and desired output. I, and I'm sure others, wasted a lot of time parsing that input and creating that output to try to help you. Now you've got a bunch of answers that work on some input file format that doesn't exist to create some output format that you don't actually want. What a waste of time...

Comment: I realize that and apologize, but I thought I made it clear it was an example.
I wouldn't be so pessimistic, though. What counts are the different methods wich can be applied, and for that I am very thankful. I will manage to modify my input if need be so that the work of people here is put to good use. 

Now to be perfectly clear. I am trying to compare different lists of movies. I want to keep in each list only the movies not found in any other. 
I haven't had time to check the code as I'm at work but I'm sure the code presented here will be really helpful in achieving that on my own.

Comment: An example typically means you're using made up data in your real format (e.g. to reduce the number of rows or columns or to not show real customer info), not that you're using a made up format! If you find an answer below that you can adapt to work on your real input and produce your real desired output that just means you got SOMETHING you can figure out how to change - that's a long way from finding the best approach to your real problem, and it doesn't even mean you modified it in the right way. Don't bother trying my answer as it has nothing in common with your now-revealed real problem.

Answer (score 1):

Please try `Python`:

```
import re

with open("./input_file", "rt") as file:
  f = file.readlines()
  cols = [re.findall(r"[\w']+", x) for x in f[3:]]

col1 = set(x[0] for x in cols)
col2 = set(x[1] for x in cols)
col3 = set(x[2] for x in cols)

print col1.difference(col2.union(col3))
print col2.difference(col1.union(col3))
print col3.difference(col1.union(col2))
```

Output:

```
set(['1'])
set(['8', 'd'])
set(['c', 'b'])
```

***EDIT***

Enhanced version to match desired formatting. Also should work with any number of columns/rows.

```
from __future__ import print_function
import re

with open("./input_file", "rt") as file:
    f = file.readlines()
    for x in f[:2]:
        print(x,end='')
    rows = [re.findall(r"(?<=\|)(.*?)(?:\|)", x) for x in f[2:]]
    col_num, col_width = len(rows[0]), len(rows[0][0])
    cols = [ set(y[x] for y in rows) for x in range(len(rows[0]))]

uniq_cols = []
for col in cols:
    uniq_cols.append(list(col.difference(set().union(*[c for c in cols if c != col]))))

for x in range(max(len(x) for x in uniq_cols)):
    print('|', end='')
    for col in uniq_cols:
        try:
            print(col[x], end='')
            print('|', end='')
        except IndexError:
            print(' '*col_width, end='')
            print('|', end='')
    print('\n', end='')
```

Output:

```
------------------------------------|
|   List1   |   List2   |   List3   |
|     1     |     8     |     c     |
|           |     d     |     b     |
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN { FS="[[:space:]]*[|][[:space:]]*" }
NR<3 { print; next }
{
    for (i=2;i<NF;i++) {
        cnt[$i]++
        inCells[NR,i] = $i
    }
}
END {
    for (inRowNr=3; inRowNr<=FNR; inRowNr++) {
        for (colNr=2; colNr<NF; colNr++) {
            val = inCells[inRowNr,colNr]
            if ( cnt[val] == 1 ) {
                outRowNr = ++colOutRowNr[colNr]
                outCells[outRowNr,colNr] = val
                numOutRows = (outRowNr > numOutRows ? outRowNr : numOutRows)
            }
        }
    }

    for (outRowNr=1; outRowNr<=numOutRows; outRowNr++) {
        printf "|"
        for (colNr=2; colNr<NF; colNr++) {
            printf "     %s     |", ((outRowNr,colNr) in outCells ? outCells[outRowNr,colNr] : " ")
        }
        print ""
    }

}
```

.

```
$ awk -f tst.awk file
------------------------------------|
|   List1   |   List2   |   List3   |
|     1     |     8     |     b     |
|           |     d     |     c     |
```

Answer (score 0):

`awk` to the rescue!

```
$ awk 'function abc(x,y,z) 
       {for(k in x) if(!(k in y || k in z)) printf "%s", FS k; 
        print ""
       } 

  NR==1{split($0,h); next} 
       {a[$1];b[$2];c[$3]}
    END{printf "%s", h[1]; abc(a,b,c); 
        printf "%s", h[2]; abc(b,a,c); 
        printf "%s", h[3]; abc(c,a,b) }' file

List1 1
List2 8 d
List3 b c
```

Usually, columnar operations are harder since the logical unit of record is the line (row).  You can transpose this back to column format I'm not sure it's needed.

Answer (score 0):

You can take 2 pass to this file using awk:

```
awk 'FNR==NR{for(i=1; i<=NF; i++) dup[$i]++; next}
  {for(i=1; i<=NF; i++) printf "%s%s", ((dup[$i]>1)? ".":$i), OFS; print ""}' file file |
  column -t
```

**Output:**

```
List1  List2  List3
1      .      .
.      .      .
.      .      .
.      .      .
.      .      .
.      .      .
.      8      b
.      d      c
```

Used `DOT` just to show blank columns in output.

---

To get the formatting right use:

```
awk 'FNR==NR{
   for(i=1; i<=NF; i++)
      dup[$i]++
   fld=NF
   next
} {
  for(i=1; i<=NF; i++)
     if (dup[$i]<=1) {
        for(j=1; j<i; j++)
           if (dup[$j]>1)
              printf "\t"
        p++
        printf "%s%s", $i, (p && p%fld == 0) ? ORS : OFS
     }
}
END{
  print ""
}' file file
```

**Output:**

```
List1  List2  List3
1      8      b
       d      c
```

Comment: Your posted output doesn't match the output I see when I run this on the provided data file.  I get a few extra columns in the first example, though it's legible.  In the second example, I get a ton of whitespace, presumably where all the duplicated values would have printed out.  Not downvoting, though, as this is a pretty creative solution and I don't think it'd be terribly difficult to clean up. :)

Comment: I have attached both the outputs in the answer and ,2nd one same as shown in question also. I will definitely check it if different data file is provided to test it.

Answer (score 0):

```
awk -F '\|'

{   l1[$2]++; l2[$3]++; l3[$4]++ }
END{
    for i in l1 {if(l2[i] > 0 || l3[i] > 0 ) delete l1[i]}
    for i in l2 {if(l1[i] > 0 || l3[i] > 0 ) delete l2[i]}
    for i in l3 {if(l1[i] > 0 || l2[i] > 0 ) delete l3[i]}

    # formatting report is left as an exercise
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Being fairly strict with your sample format, here's a shell script which generates your expected output, aside from the very first line.  Basically, you read the data into separate columns, and record all the data in the table.  Then generate columns of data without the duplicated data.  Then print the de-duplicated data out.  This will break if you have data that contains spaces, but to fix that you just need to adjust $IFS to match your delimiter.

This is also ksh93-specific.  I don't know how much will break in bash, but I don't like bash all that much.  I think it should be fairly readable if you'd like to reimplement in another language, but it's probably easier to just install ksh93 on a Linux or UNIX system somewhere (RHEL and Ubuntu both ship with a package, as do most common systems).

```
#!/usr/bin/ksh
IFS="${IFS}|" # also split on pipe

[[ -f "${1:-}" ]] || { print -- "'${1:-}' is not a file" >&2; exit 1; }
exec 3<$1

read firstline <&3
read -A headings <&3
# prune first element, due to weird line splitting
headings=("${headings[@]:1}")


# build data structure of all columns and aggregated values
typeset -a data
typeset -A counter
typeset -i row=0
while read -A line
do
  col=0
  #for v in ${line[@]}
  for v in "${line[@]:1}" # ignore false first element
  do
    data[$((col++))][$row]=$v
    (( counter[$v] += 1 ))
  done
  ((row++))
done <&3

# remove duplicated data from columns
row=0
typeset -i maxrows=0
typeset -a deduped
for col in {1..${#data[@]}}
do
  c=$(( col - 1 ))
  row=0
  for v in ${data[$c][@]}
  do
    [[ ${counter[$v]} -eq 1 ]] && deduped[$c][$((row++))]=${v}
  done
  [[ $row -gt $maxrows ]] && maxrows=$row
done

# pad short columns with empty elements and calculate widths
typeset -a widths
for col in {1..${#deduped[@]}}
do
  c=$((col-1))
  widths[$c]=${#headings[$c]} # default to heading width
  while [[ ${#deduped[$c][@]} -lt $maxrows ]]
  do
    deduped[$c][${#deduped[$c][@]}]=''
    [[ ${widths[$c]} -lt ${#v} ]] && widths[$c]=${#v}
  done
  (( widths[$c] += 2 )) # allow for a space on each side
done

# print the table out
# header first
format='|'
for w in "${widths[@]}"
do
  format="${format}%=${w}s|"
done
format="${format}\n"
printf "$format" "${headings[@]}"

# then table
row=0
while [[ $row -lt $maxrows ]]
do
  typeset -a r
  for col in {1..${#deduped[@]}}
  do
    c=$((col-1))
    r[$c]="${deduped[$c][$row]}"
  done
  printf "$format" "${r[@]}"
  ((row++))
done
```

working on your test file:

```
$ ./test.ksh testfile
| List1 | List2 | List3 |
|   1   |   8   |   b   |
|       |   d   |   c   |
```

Comment: If your input format doesn't actually start with a pipe, comment out the "prune first column" part after reading headings in, and use the alternate `for` statement (the one without a `:1` at the end).  I'm not entirely sure why it works that way - probably something with the order of chars in `$IFS` or something).

Comment: Poor planning, mostly. :)

Answer (score 0):

This response focuses on the general case in which there are n columns, for any n >= 1.  This makes the program a little longer than would otherwise be the case.

Since the OP referred to Excel, this response also assumes that the data is available as a file with delimiter-separated values (e.g. TSV or pipe-separated).  For ease of reading, I'll assume an uncomplicated CSV, like so:

```
List1,List2,List3
1,2,3
2,3,4
3,4,5
4,5,6
5,6,7
6,7,a
7,8,b
a,d,c
```

This response will also assume that in the output, the ordering of values in each column is unimportant. (The alternative case is left as an exercise for the reader :-)

The final assumption is that we can use the input field-separator as the output field-separator (OFS=FS).

Here then is the awk program, which does not require more than standard awk:

```
awk -F, '
  # print an m by n matrix, a:
  function printm(a,m,n, i,j, row) {
    for(i=1;i<=m;i++) {
      row=a[i,1];
      for(j=2;j<=n;j++) {row = row OFS a[i,j]}
      print row;
    }
  }

  function maxfields(i)  { if (MAXFIELDS =="" || MAXFIELDS<i ) {MAXFIELDS=i; } }
  function maxcounter(i) { if (MAXCOUNTER=="" || MAXCOUNTER<i) {MAXCOUNTER=i;} }
  # process one line of input:
  function assemble(  i) {
     for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) {
       if ($i in seen) { delete col[$i] }
       else { seen[$i]; col[$i]=i; }
     }
  }
  function finish(  i,x) {
    for(i=1; i<=MAXFIELDS; i++) { counter[i]=1 }
    for (x in col) { a[ counter[col[x]], col[x] ] = x; 
                     maxcounter(counter[col[x]]++); }
    printm(a, MAXCOUNTER, MAXFIELDS)
  }
  BEGIN {OFS=FS}
  NR==1 {print; next;}
  {maxfields(NF); assemble();}
  END { finish(); } '
```

Output:

```
List1,List2,List3
1,d,b
,8,c
```